# Detect if file is locked via Samba JCIFS

Tags: locking, jcifs

I'm looking for an efficient method for determining whether or not a file is locked (eg. if a user has it open in MS Word for editing) via JCIFS.

Is there a direct method for this, or will I need some clever custom code to achieve it?